Possible to tag shortcuts (.lnk files) in Windows 10?
Whilst attempting to group folders using Windows built-in "right click > group by > tags" in File Explorer, I'm having problems when it comes to shortcuts 
What I'm looking at
Let's say I want the "Music" shortcut to be tagged.
I manually go open the shortcuts destination folder, & I place my desktop.ini with the following parameters:
[ViewState]
Mode=
Vid=
FolderType=Generic

[{F29F85E0-4FF9-1068-AB91-08002B27B3D9}]
Prop5=31, ;System

Save, and to my surprise- it's still unsuccessful.
I've also tried using InTag, but it seems to produce the same result.
Any ideas? Appreciate you 
❗ Might be worth checking this out: ExifTool LNK TagNames

Expecting: Tag to be applied to a .lnk file (shortcut), thus allowing it to be grouped by tag.
Result: Tag IS SEEMINGLY APPLIED, however is not producing the expected result.
